# What are the differences between Drupal 7 and 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

What will be the main differences/enhancements between Drupal 7 and 8? 
I've found some articles on Drupal 8 (Some by Dries himself) but haven't exactly found a consolidated list on the main enhancements of what's to come. Even though Drupal 8 hasn't been released, it should be released anytime soon since Drupal 7 is already on version 7.9. This should help newcomers to expert Drupal users and developers.

Comment: Asking the developers for a changelog seems like an incredibly reasonable thing to do...

Comment: I'm definitely not asking for something like a changelog, sorry if I didn't express myself appropriately. Just wanted to know the main features that will be included/excluded. For example, full HTML5 support, Symfony2 components added, core modules that will be excluded, modules that will included to the core of Drupal 8, etc. Hopefully someone, maybe a contributor, might know and share some details on this.

Comment: That sounds like a changelog to me! :)

Comment: While off topic it should be noted that Drupal 8 will not be released for at LEAST another 18 months, please see http://drupal.cocomore.com/blog/new-users-universally-do-not-understand-drupal-8-not-near-release

Comment: http://drupal.org/list-changes/drupal?to_branch=8.x